# How to append to <head> with PHP in the middle of the page?

Tags: php, html, css, head

I have an HTML "chunk" of code with **HTML and JS** in it so I could easily **include it with PHP**. I also want it to have **CSS styling** but according to standards you are not "*allowed*" to do that - while it works it makes the page invalid. CSS is only allowed in `<head>` and not in the middle of the page (not untill HTML5.2 at least). So I thought about appending similarly named but separate .css file in the head, but with PHP and **not JS** (for performance sake)

```php
<head>
<!-- PHP needs to include button.css here AFTER $App->INC("button"); has been called -->
</head>

<body>
<?php
$App->INC("button");
//This basically does 'require_once("button")';
//What do I need to add to the INC method to include css file in the head?
//Similar to $("head").append() but with PHP
?>
</body>
```

css file with the same name should be added to a `<head>` section.

**PS**:
This may seem as a design flaw and may as well be but here is the thought behind this.

1. I have a piece of code that when included in the right place of the
   body generates a "loading screen" (or other UI elements that
   can't/shouldn't be nested anywhere else but in the `<body>` of
   the website.
2. It's got styling in a separate file
3. I send it to other user
4. They include it with a method of an "App" class which only does two
   things: includes the file itself and css file nearby
5. Then they only use 1 line of code to put it where they want it and
   not in 2-3 other places so the code is more manageable

Example:

[image: Structure]

Comment: Why can't you add the css where it's supposed to be? You can make a dynamic css file with php.

Comment: `PHP needs to include button.css here AFTER $App->INC("button"); has been called` - why? Why not just include the CSS file using the `<link>` tag?

Comment: @waterloomatt
It may be a design flaw but I always thought that it would've been better to do this:

call $App->INC("btn"); in the body ONCE and add head inclusion inside the method

than 
call $App->INC("btn"); then ALSO include css via link

It comes with an idea of "modularity" so I could just send these two files to some other user that needs them (loading screen for example) and then they just include it once without ever needing to go elsewhere to include styles as well. It becomes some version of a "hell" when you need to go to 2 different places to enable one "module"/chunk

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly what you are trying to archive. For me this sounds like that: You want to have a single piece of code that adds a module (or whatever) to your app and this module adds code to the `body` and `head`. Maybe your app should provide the functionality for your module to inject content into `head` / `body`. Have a look at the idea of the WordPress hook system: https://www.wpsuperstars.net/wordpress-hooks/

Comment: @Cakasim
I guess a hook is exactly what I am looking for - I've heard this term a while back. But yes you understood me correctly: single piece of code that adds a module to both ```body``` and ```head```. Thing is **it is important where you put it in ```body``` but not so much where the styling is put in the** ```head``` - you can just append it before the end of head section.
Anyway it worked perfectly well with ```<style>``` being in the same file as the "module" code but as I stated before - it invalidates because of standards and such

Comment: @Glen Ok nice, you may have a look at my updated answer. This is some kind of WordPress hook thing :D

Comment: Are you building a framework of sorts? Sounds like one of your primary concerns is to make reusable components that render themselves along with their own CSS. One idea would be for each component to render itself but not to know anything about the CSS. The CSS would simply reside in a global file which you include in your layout file.

Comment: @waterloomatt
Exactly. Well "framework" is a big word but yeah :) Reusable components - absolutely, I always called them "chunks", I guess wrongfully so.
Moving components' CSS styles to the "core" of the app or a "global file" - restricts users that would like to make their own custom styled components unless they go to global styling sheet and add their styling there, but it kinda defeats the purpose of a reusable component, doesn't it? Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: It is the intended use case of *cascading* stylesheets to override each other. So why not including an empty `custom.css` (after the global CSS) that users may edit to cutomize things.

Comment: One possible way would be to include a `default.css` which has default styling. Then users can add a `custom.css` file beneath it (in the `<head>`) which would override styling. So for example, default.css would have `.button { color: blue; }` and the user can override this by adding a custom.css file with `.button { color: red; }`. This way users can simply include a new CSS file instead of having to customize/override the PHP components themselves. Just a thought.

Comment: @Cakasim
Why not include an empty css where? I want it to be packaged WITH the structure and I don't want it to have to be manually added anywhere else but with the main "include" method. I may be not understanding something, I'm not that good of a dev tbh

Comment: @waterloomatt
they would have to include a new css file **by hand** in the head section. That's what I'm trying to get rid off. And yeah there are other css files in the head already for general styling, that aint exactly a problem, I just want additional styling (whether ```<link>``` or ```<style>``` to be appended to the head when php includes the "module" from within the ```<body>```. Right now I think about just scanning the whole **reusable components folder and including all css files** by default whether you are using the component that requires it or not. Kinda what @Cakasim suggested

Comment: Just add an empty `custom.css` file to your project and include this CSS file with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/custom.css">` in your HTML `<head>`. One may add custom CSS rules to this file or override existing (default) rules.

Comment: @Cakasim
But that would make it less "modular".
1) User A makes "loading screen" chunk, edits custom.css to accommodate it, packs it up, done
2) User B makes "scroll to top button" chunk, edits custom.css to accommodate it, packs it up, done
3) User C downloads "loading screen" includes both files on his website - everything works fine
4) User C then downloads "scroll to top button", includes both files on his website, now only "scroll to top button" works while "loading screen" doesnt.
That's the whole reason why I want to **append**

Comment: I don't need to actually override anything, just to append/add to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```php
<?php
ob_start();
$App->INC("button");
$button = ob_get_clean();
?>
<head>
<!-- Do your inclue here -->
</head>

<body>
<?= $button ?>
</body>
```

You can put the `ob_start()` / `ob_get_clean()` stuff inside `button.php` and return the content via your `INC()` method. Then you can save the content directly into `$button` like this: `$button = $App->INC("button");`.

But your example looks like a design problem. However I hope this will do the trick.

---

This could be a possible redesign:

```php
<?php

$App->loadModule('button'); // Loads the module, the module registers stylesheets and content.

$App->loadModule('another_module'); // Load more modules ...

<head>
<?php $App->renderModuleStylesheets(); ?>
</head>

<body>
<?php $App->renderModuleContent(); ?>
</body>
```

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for but this would still require me to write inclusion code in TWO different places (```<body>``` tag and buffer). Ideally I'd want to get rid of buffer code **OR** wrap it inside the $App class but buffer commands are also place-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the CSS directly in the component itself, or expect the component to dynamically load the relevant CSS, then it could be quite difficult to maintain or customize. I am not saying you shouldn't go this route but be careful about asking your components to do too much.

A hook system as pointed out in the comments is one way to handle this.

Another simple way is to provide default styling which users can override. This is probably the simplest way to allow different styling for each component.

```
<head>
<!-- Provide some defaults. Users should not customize this one. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">

<!-- User's can customize this file to override the default styling.-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
</head>

<body>
<?php $App->INC("button"); ?>
</body>
```

**button.php** - is only responsible for rendering a button. The separate CSS files will actually style it.

```
<?php
echo <input type"submit" class="button" value="Submit">
```

**default.css** - applies default styling

```
.button {
    color: blue;
}
```

**custom.css** - overrides the default styling

```
.button {
    color: red;
}
```

Final note, you may also want to look into using a main template file which sub-views inherit. This helps to reduce the number of full HTML files which link to your CSS files. The idea is to have 1 (or a few) template files that views inject themselves into. Here's some pseudo code.

**frontend.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Links to CSS files here. -->
</head>

<body>
<?php $placeholder('body'); ?>
</body>
```

**Login.php**

```
<?php inherits('frontend.php')->body; ?>
<form id="login">
...
```

**Register.php**

```
<?php inherits('frontend.php')->body; ?>
<form id="register">
...
```

**About-Us.php**

```
<?php inherits('frontend.php')->body; ?>
<p>About Us</p>
...
```

Comment: This is another good option, some sort of template engine. But, DRY and use https://twig.symfony.com/ or any other good template engine.